# Criação de duas tabelas em SQL a partir de uma única tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fui praticar alguns comandos em SQL no StrataScratch e me deparei com o seguinte desafio de uma entrevista para Amazon:

Escreva um query que identifique usuários ativos que voltam a comprar.
Um usuário ativo que volta a comprar é aquele que realiza uma segunda compra 7 dias após a primeira compra.
Crie um output com uma lista de user_ids desses usuários.
A maioria das respostas é assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.user_id
FROM amazon_transactions a1
JOIN amazon_transactions a2 ON a1.user_id = a2.user_id
AND a1.id <> a2.id
AND DATEDIFF(day, a1.created_at, a2.created_at) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
ORDER BY a1.user_id
```

**Alguém saberia me explicar o por que criar duas tabelas a partir de uma?**
Foram criadas duas tabelas:

- amazon_transactions a1
- amazon_transactions a2

| id: int |
| --- |
| user_id: int |
| item: varchar |
| created_at: datetime |
| revenue : int |

Tabela: amazon_transactions

| id | user_id | item | created_at | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 109 | milk | 2020-03-03 | 123 |
| 2 | 139 | biscuit | 2020-03-18 | 421 |
| 3 | 120 | milk | 2020-03-18 | 176 |
| 4 | 108 | banana | 2020-03-18 | 862 |
| 5 | 130 | milk | 2020-03-28 | 333 |
| 6 | 103 | bread | 2020-03-29 | 862 |
| 7 | 122 | banana | 2020-03-07 | 952 |
| 8 | 125 | bread | 2020-03-13 | 317 |
| 9 | 139 | bread | 2020-03-30 | 929 |
| 10 | 141 | banana | 2020-03-17 | 812 |
| 11 | 116 | bread | 2020-03-31 | 226 |
| 12 | 128 | bread | 2020-03-04 | 112 |
| 13 | 146 | biscuit | 2020-03-04 | 362 |
| 14 | 119 | banana | 2020-03-28 | 127 |
| 15 | 142 | bread | 2020-03-09 | 503 |
| 16 | 122 | bread | 2020-03-0 | 593 |
| 17 | 128 | biscuit | 2020-03-24 | 160 |
| 18 | 112 | banana | 2020-03-24 | 262 |
| 19 | 149 | banana | 2020-03-29 | 382 |
| 20 | 100 | banana | 2020-03-18 | 599 |
| 21 | 130 | milk | 2020-03-16 | 604 |
| 22 | 103 | milk | 2020-03-31 | 290 |
| 23 | 112 | banana | 2020-03-23 | 523 |
| 24 | 102 | bread | 2020-03-25 | 325 |
| 25 | 120 | biscui | 2020-03-21 | 858 |
| 26 | 109 | bread | 2020-03-22 | 432 |
| 27 | 101 | milk | 2020-03-01 | 449 |
| 28 | 138 | milk | 2020-03-19 | 961 |
| 29 | 100 | milk | 2020-03-29 | 410 |
| 30 | 129 | milk | 2020-03-02 | 771 |
| 31 | 123 | milk | 2020-03-31 | 434 |
| 32 | 104 | biscuit | 2020-03-31 | 957 |
| 33 | 110 | bread | 2020-03-13 | 210 |
| 34 | 143 | bread | 2020-03-27 | 870 |
| 35 | 130 | milk | 2020-03-12 | 176 |
| 36 | 128 | milk | 2020-03-28 | 498 |
| 37 | 133 | banana | 2020-03-21 | 837 |
| 38 | 150 | banana | 2020-03-20 | 927 |
| 39 | 120 | milk | 2020-03-27 | 793 |
| 40 | 109 | bread | 2020-03-02 | 362 |
| 41 | 110 | bread | 2020-03-13 | 262 |
| 42 | 140 | milk | 2020-03-09 | 468 |
| 43 | 112 | banana | 2020-03-04 | 381 |
| 44 | 117 | biscuit | 2020-03-19 | 831 |
| 45 | 137 | banana | 2020-03-23 | 490 |
| 46 | 130 | bread | 2020-03-09 | 149 |
| 47 | 133 | bread | 2020-03-08 | 658 |
| 48 | 143 | milk | 2020-03-11 | 317 |
| 49 | 111 | biscuit | 2020-03-23 | 204 |
| 50 | 150 | banana | 2020-03-04 | 299 |

Output esperado:

| user_id |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 103 |
| 105 |
| 109 |
| 110 |

Comment: Na realidade não se "cria" e sim se instancia ("chama") a mesma tabela duas vezes , para que se possa comparar registros de um mesmo "user_id" , no caso em um intervalo de datas "created_at". "DATEDIFF" é uma function que retorna um intervalo de dias entre duas datas. Outra solução seria usar um subselect com EXISTS , eu faria assim. Ajudou ?

Comment: Entendi agora. Muito obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como Motta respondeu acima, você não está criando, mais instanciando a tabela e comparando com ela mesma, quando o id for diferente.
Como a operação de JOIN só retorna quando a comparação é verdadeira, se houver outra transação com o período informado de 7 dias será verdade.

Se fosse utilizar a clausula **WHERE EXISTS**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.user_id
FROM amazon_transactions a1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM amazon_transactions a2
    WHERE a1.user_id = a2.user_id
        AND a1.id <> a2.id
        AND DATEDIFF(day, a1.created_at, a2.created_at) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
)
ORDER BY a1.user_id;
```

A diferença de desempenho entre EXISTS e JOIN pode depender do banco de dados específico que você está usando e da otimização que o otimizador de consulta do banco de dados pode realiza.

Como possui um volume de dados grandes, o ideal seria testar e verificar o plano de execução das query para ver qual é mais eficiente.

Comment: Entendido. Muito obrigada pela ajuda, Lucas!